# Decode string in Scala/Play Framework when passed to a view and used in Javascript

Tags: scala, playframework

I am passing a string from a controller to a view in Play.  I am using this string as a variable in a Javascript routine inside the view using Scala.

It is being encoded -- the single quotes are being translated as:

```
&#x27;
```

--- but I need them to be single quotes inside the Javascript.

Here is the controller code:

```
String jsonString = "{cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'}, {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}]}";

return ok(piechart.render(jsonString));
```

Here is the view code:

```
@(jsonString: String)

@main(null) {
  <script type="text/javascript">

var jsonString = "@jsonString";
            console.log("jsonString: " + jsonString);
            var newJSON = jsonString.replace("&#x27;", "'");
            console.log("newJSON: " + newJSON);
            var jsonDecoded = decodeURI(jsonString);
            console.log("JSON Decoded: " + jsonDecoded); 
</script>
}
```

The output is the same each of the console statements, except for the replace method which seems to replace the first occurrence, but no more:

```
jsonString: {cols: [{id: &#x27;task&#x27;, label: &#x27;Task&#x27;, type: &#x27;string&#x27;}, {id: &#x27;hours&#x27;, label: &#x27;Hours per Day&#x27;, type: &#x27;number&#x27;}],rows: [{c:[{v: &#x27;Work&#x27;}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Eat&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Commute&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Watch TV&#x27;}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Sleep&#x27;}, {v:7, f:&#x27;7.000&#x27;}]}]}
newJSON: {cols: [{id: 'task&#x27;, label: &#x27;Task&#x27;, type: &#x27;string&#x27;}, {id: &#x27;hours&#x27;, label: &#x27;Hours per Day&#x27;, type: &#x27;number&#x27;}],rows: [{c:[{v: &#x27;Work&#x27;}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Eat&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Commute&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Watch TV&#x27;}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Sleep&#x27;}, {v:7, f:&#x27;7.000&#x27;}]}]}
JSON Decoded: {cols: [{id: &#x27;task&#x27;, label: &#x27;Task&#x27;, type: &#x27;string&#x27;}, {id: &#x27;hours&#x27;, label: &#x27;Hours per Day&#x27;, type: &#x27;number&#x27;}],rows: [{c:[{v: &#x27;Work&#x27;}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Eat&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Commute&#x27;}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Watch TV&#x27;}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: &#x27;Sleep&#x27;}, {v:7, f:&#x27;7.000&#x27;}]}]}
```

The replace and the decodeURI methods do not decode the string.

Is there something else I need to do to get the string to use the single quotes?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex on the replace worked:

```
var newJSON = jsonString.replace(/&#x27;/g, "'");
console.log("newJSON: " + newJSON);
```

Output:

```
newJSON: {cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'}, {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}]}
```